# Cómo puedo aumentar el valor de un Map

Tags: java, bucles, csv, map, hashmap

estoy intentando obtener un  Map<String, Integer> donde las claves son los equipos de fútbol y los valores la suma de todos los goles que han marcado como local. Los datos salen de un CSV donde cada línea es un partido con su equipo local, los goles que este metió y otros datos que no son necesarios para esto. Quiero recorrer el CSV y que si el equipo no está añadido al resultado, lo añada junto a los goles en ese partido, en cambio, si el equipo ya está añadido al resultado, que sume los goles de este nuevo partido a los que ya estaban añadidos. He intentado varias cosas, pero al final solo lo he dejado así porque no sé qué más hacer:

```
public Map<String, Integer> golesTotalesPorEquipoLocal() {
        Map<String, Integer> resultado = new HashMap<>();
        for (PremierLeague p:partidos) {
            if (resultado.containsKey(p.getLocal())) {
                //si el local ya está como clave, sumar los goles de este partido a los anteriores

            }else {
                //si el local no está como clave, poner el local en la clave y los goles en el 
                //valor
                resultado.put(p.getLocal(), p.getGolesLocal());
            }
        }
        return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que obtener el resultado actual guardado y modificarlo, añadiendo los goles:

```java
if (resultado.containsKey(p.getLocal())) {
   int goles = resultado.get(p.getLocal()) + p.getGolesLocal();
   resultado.put(p.getLocal(), goles);
}else {
    resultado.put(p.getLocal(), p.getGolesLocal());
}
```